# Jekyll: Printing Nested Front Matter

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to print my front matter to the page, but I'm having a problem printing this nested data to the page.

**.md file**

```
gallery:
   row:
      image: { url: 'img.jpg', ratio: '1.7486338798' }
      image: { url: 'img.jpg', ratio: '1.7486338798' }
```

**post.html**

```
{% for img in page.gallery.row.image %}
  <img src="{{ img.url }}" alt="" data-aspect-ratio="{{ img.ratio }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Nothing's showing up in my HTML output. Am I doing something wrong here? Am I nesting Front Matter in YAML correctly?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Had someone help me out over on the [Jekyll Github Page](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3564). Answer below:

I seemed to be redefining the hash. The below method works:

```
gallery:
   row:
      image:
        - { url: 'img.jpg', ratio: '1.7486338798' }
        - { url: 'img.jpg', ratio: '1.7486338798' }
```